# How to view details about a network tag in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

There is an option to view "Tags" under IAM but I dont see any option to see network tags in a similar way. I would like to know where the tags are utilized in my environment (which VM's) and also the firewall function they are tied to. Checking to see if anyone can assist with this.

Comment: there is no API for that. you have to parse all your VM, extract their network tag, if any, and match it with your existing firewall rules

Comment: Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct method as “`Tags section`” for network tags but another workaround is:

You can find network tag of instance by:

1. In the Compute`Compute Engine` section go to `VM instances`.
2. Select the one VM in the details section and you can find the **Network tags** section.

[image]

Or you can add network tags as shown below by adding select the property **Network tags** and enter the tags you want to filter on in the column display option. [image]

After finding the network tag ex:gke-cluster-3-50e87bb4-node, you can find the list of compute engine instances which are associated to them by using command:

```
$ gcloud compute instances list --filter="tags.items=gke-cluster-3-50e87bb4-node"
NAME: gke-cluster-3-default-pool-ca0f09e4-28i6
ZONE: us-central1-c
MACHINE_TYPE: e2-medium
PREEMPTIBLE: 
INTERNAL_IP: 10.128.0.56
EXTERNAL_IP: 34.172.252.28
STATUS: RUNNING

NAME: gke-cluster-3-default-pool-ca0f09e4-iub6
ZONE: us-central1-c
MACHINE_TYPE: e2-medium
PREEMPTIBLE: 
INTERNAL_IP: 10.128.0.57
EXTERNAL_IP: 34.67.167.222
STATUS: RUNNING

NAME: gke-cluster-3-default-pool-ca0f09e4-jxnq
ZONE: us-central1-c
MACHINE_TYPE: e2-medium
PREEMPTIBLE: 
INTERNAL_IP: 10.128.0.58
EXTERNAL_IP: 35.193.160.51
STATUS: RUNNING
```

To find the **firewall functions/rules** which are associated with the **network tag,** Go to **VPC network** in the navigation menu then select the **firewall** section.

[image]

In the filter section add the network tag “gke-cluster-3-50e87bb4-node". Then you can find the firewall associated with it.